# Npx hardhat could not determine executable to run

Tags: hardhat

I am trying to follow [this guide](https://hardhat.org/tutorial/creating-a-new-hardhat-project.html) and I am struggling running hardhat. After following the commands in the article:

```
mkdir hardhat-tutorial
cd hardhat-tutorial
npm init --yes
npm install --save-dev hardhat
npx hardhat
```

I get an error stating `npm ERR!  could not determine executable to run`. The hardhat tool can be run by navigating to the `npm_modules/hardhat` directory however this seems to be interfering with the commands later in the tutorial due to the tool being in a different directory to the files it is being used on.

I'm not sure if I have fundamentally misunderstood how hardhat is supposed to work. Are you supposed to install it in each project and have your project directory be within `npm_modules/hardhat` or have I messed up the install/configuartion?

There appears to have already been a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70341380/unable-to-run-npx-hardhat-on-windows) covering this issue but sadly it was deleted and I have not managed to find another solution.

Comment: I am also seeing this error when following a hardhat tutorial. I am following this tutorial: https://hardhat.org/getting-started/ Thanks for the information that the hardhat.js app is in "npm_modules". I have the hardhat.js application installed here: `node_modules/hardhat`. I was surprised the hardhat instructions did not mention the prerequisite of installing `node.js` and `npm`, seems like they are leaving out some critical details in their tutorials... Or they expect the end-user to know everything.

Comment: Looks like the version changed from the tutorial. I see hardhat as this version:
 Welcome to Hardhat v2.8.0 ‍ However, the tutorial is using version 2.0.8.

Comment: I am referring to this tutorial, by the way (btw): https://hardhat.org/getting-started/

Comment: Looks like the version of hardhat in your tutorial page is even older! They are using Hardhat v2.0.0. https://hardhat.org/tutorial/creating-a-new-hardhat-project.html#_3-creating-a-new-hardhat-project

Comment: I got this error because I typed "harhat" instead of "hardhat"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same issue then it worked for me by specifying the latest version of hardhat during the install, eg.:

```
npm install --save-dev "hardhat@^2.8.0"
```

With this no need to go into the `node_modules/hardhat` folder in order to run `npx hardhat`

Comment: Excellent! This works. I noticed that when I try to address vulnerabilities `npm` tells me about that I receive the error again. Looks like it is impossible to win. These are the vulnerabilities and the command `npm` tells me to run after the "npm install ..." command completes: 
`9 moderate severity vulnerabilities

To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
  npm audit fix --force`

Answer (score 1):

The best thing to do is create a new hardhat project, because here and there you will get stuck. Faced the same problem

Answer (score 0):

To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:

```
npm audit fix --force
```

Run `npm audit` for details.

```
dee-MacBook-Pro-2 polygon-hardhat % npm audit fix --force
npm WARN using --force Recommended protections disabled.
npm WARN audit Updating hardhat to 0.0.7,which is a SemVer major change.
npm WARN deprecated mkdirp@0.3.5: Legacy versions of mkdirp are no longer supported. Please update to mkdirp 1.x. (Note that the API surface has changed to use Promises in 1.x.)

added 4 packages, removed 333 packages, changed 5 packages, and audited 10 packages in 4s

found 0 vulnerabilities
dee@Dee-MacBook-Pro-2 polygon-hardhat % npx hardhat
npm ERR! could not determine executable to run

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/dee/.npm/_logs/2022-02-13T16_54_02_999Z-debug-0.log
dee@Dee-MacBook-Pro-2 polygon-hardhat %
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you are not using yarn
try this

```
mkdir Smart-contracts
cd Smart-contracts
npm init
yarn add --dev hardhat
```

then type `npx hardhat`
and there will be no problem.